# for-loop inconsistencies in R on i+1:5 expression

Tags: r, for-loop

Although it is not a good practice, I am using a double for loop to perform a calculation. To illustrate the error I am getting, the following for loop would do. Why is the 'j' counter exceeding '5' in the inner for loop?

```
> for(i in 1:5){
+   for(j in i+1:5)
+     print(c(i,j))
+ }
[1] 1 2
[1] 1 3
[1] 1 4
[1] 1 5
[1] 1 6
[1] 2 3
[1] 2 4
[1] 2 5
[1] 2 6
[1] 2 7
[1] 3 4
[1] 3 5
[1] 3 6
[1] 3 7
[1] 3 8
[1] 4 5
[1] 4 6
[1] 4 7
[1] 4 8
[1] 4 9
[1] 5 6
[1] 5 7
[1] 5 8
[1] 5 9
[1]  5 10
```

Comment: Because `+` takes precedence over `:`.  Use `for(i in i + (1:5))`

Comment: It looks like the `:` is taking precedence in the results.  Otherwise `i+1:5` would have different lengths for each value of `i`.  On testing it definitely seems that `:` is taking precedence over `+`, and the displayed result is what you get when that is the case.  Was `for(j in 1:5)` or `for(j in i:5)` what was intended?

Comment: @Andrie Thanks! I need to do  -- `for(j in (i+1):5)` to get what I want

Comment: @Andrie This is not correct. The `:` operator has a higher priority than `+`. Therefore `for (j in i +1:5)` is identical to `for (j in i +(1:5))`.

Comment: in the first round of your loop,  `i==1` and `1+5 == 6`...your loop is doing `1+1,1+2..1+5,2+1,2+2..2+5`  :)

Answer (score 8):

> Why is the 'j' counter exceeding '5' in the inner for loop?

`for(j in i+1:5)` is equivalent of `for(j in i+(1:5))` which can in turn be developed to `for(j in (i+1):(i+5))`

The reason can be found [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html)

> ```
> The following unary and binary operators are defined. They are listed in precedence groups, from highest to lowest.
>
> :: :::    access variables in a namespace
> $ @   component / slot extraction
> [ [[  indexing
> ^ exponentiation (right to left)
> - +   unary minus and plus
> : sequence operator ###
> %any% special operators (including %% and %/%)
> * /   multiply, divide
> + -   (binary) add, subtract ###
> ```

I added the ### to the operators which interest us here, the *sequence* is of higher precedence than the *binary add* so adding `i` will be done to the whole sequence once it has been computed.

If you wish to keep in the range `(i+1):5` you have to take care of a special case, where `i` is `5` as your sequence will become `6:5`.

So finally your code could be:

```
for (i in 1:5){
    s <- min(i+1,5) # Per Ben Bolker comment
    for (j in s:5) {
      print(c(i,j))
    }
}
```

Which output:

```
[1] 1 2
[1] 1 3
[1] 1 4
[1] 1 5
[1] 2 3
[1] 2 4
[1] 2 5
[1] 3 4
[1] 3 5
[1] 4 5
[1] 5 5
```

Comment: why not `s <- ifelse(i<5,i+1,5)` or `s <- min(i+1,5)` ?

Comment: @BenBolker probably because I'm use to do more complex things within ifelse and like to see it as a `if [...] else [...]` block. `s <- min(i+5,5)` sounds a better solution, I'll edit.

Comment: @BenBolker I'm reluctant to put logic within assignment, in an algorithm it's easiest to represent an assignment after the logical choice has been done (my point of view, not a rule).

Comment: fair enough.  Stylistic differences.  The `x <- if [...] else [...]` idiom seems to be fairly common in R (`ifelse` has its own pecularities)

Comment: @BenBolker As I'm not an R expert and playing with a lot of languages I try to keep with the generic style every language will allow for this kind of case, so *if condition assignment else other assignment* is generally more portable from language to language :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you intended to type

```
for(i in 1:5){
  for(j in (i+1):5)
    print(c(i,j))
}
#[1] 1 2
#[1] 1 3
#[1] 1 4
#[1] 1 5
#[1] 2 3
#[1] 2 4
#[1] 2 5
#[1] 3 4
#[1] 3 5
#[1] 4 5
#[1] 5 6
#[1] 5 5
```

The `:` operator is treated with higher priority than `+`. Therefore you have

```
#> (1+2):5
#[1] 3 4 5
```

whereas

```
#> 1+2:5
#[1] 3 4 5 6
```

However, even in the case of a definition of the delimiter of the inner loop with `(i+1):5`, you still have one output where the variable `j` exceeds 5. This occurs during the last iteration of the outer loop, where you have the inner `for` loop delimited by `(j in 6:5)` when `i` is equal to 5. In this last iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will be decreasing - in contrast to the previous loops - with `j` going from 6 to 5.

Not sure if this helps resolving your problem, but I sure hope so.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot parentheses/overlooked operator precedence:

```
for (i in 1:5){
    for (j in (i+1):5)
    print(c(i,j))
}
```

Comment: did you test your answer ? for i = 5 the first j will be 6. (at least it should be noted)

Comment: @Ben Bolker: I think my inital answer was correct. i+1:5 is actually interpreted as i+(1:5). The paranthesis in your code sample is unnecessary. Instead I guess Angade was looking for (i+1):5. But the comment concerning i=5 is useful, thanks for that.

Comment: Sorry if I messed up your answer, but: OP wanted to know why `j` exceeded 5 in the inner loop, and indeed it would if `i==5`.  Perhaps the issue is that it should be `min(i+1,5):5`.  Feel free to roll back/edit appropriately.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think this works for me  
`> for(i in 1:5){
+   for(j in (i+1):5)
+     print(c(i,j))
+ }
[1] 1 2
[1] 1 3
[1] 1 4
[1] 1 5
[1] 2 3
[1] 2 4
[1] 2 5
[1] 3 4
[1] 3 5
[1] 4 5
[1] 5 6
[1] 5 5`

Comment: Note that you still have one case (the second last output) where `j` exceeds 5, as discussed in my answer above.

Comment: @BenBolker I rolled back to revision 2, as the statement in revision 3 was false :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After I typed my answer I was surprised to see that the code was already modified as I suggested and I thought that I overlooked it, but it was in fact a re-edit. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean `for(j in 1:5)` or `for(j in i:5)`?  The displayed result is certainly the expected result of the displayed code and that seems consistent to me.