# R Outcome of addition of logical values depends of first value

Tags: r, logical-operators

I have a behaviour in R which I don't understand. Maybe there is a logical answer for that. If I sum logical values (or vectors with logical values) I get an integer (or vector with integers). But if I use `!` (NOT) to first value of the summation I get logical data types.

```
> TRUE  + TRUE
[1] 2
> !TRUE + !TRUE
[1] FALSE
> FALSE + FALSE
[1] 0
> !TRUE + TRUE
[1] FALSE
> TRUE  + !TRUE
[1] 1
```

Is there a reason for this behaviour?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Have a look at operator precedence (`?Syntax`)... The addition is made before negation, so you get the logical negation of your addition result. (the only case where I'm unsure on the order is `!TRUE + !TRUE`, I assume the RHS is evaluated first so it become `!TRUE + FALSE` which in turn become `!1` so `FALSE` at end)

Comment: [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31567731/3627607) (my answer for the same cause for another problem)

Comment: @Tensibai Thank you very much for this replay which answers my question. Please, write it as answer t my question. So can can give you credits. By the way, what means RHS? Right hand s....?

Comment: Right hand side (of operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at operator precedence (`?Syntax`).

The addition is made before negation, so you get the logical negation of your addition result.

The only case where I'm unsure on the order is `!TRUE + !TRUE`, I assume the RHS (Right Handed Side) is evaluated first so it become `!TRUE + FALSE` which in turn become `!1` (1+0, note the coercion to integer here) and so it give `FALSE` at end.

[related answer of myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31567731/3627607) about operator precedence.